# Sequelize - Incorporate stores into retailers after obtaining the latter

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm really new to Sequelize and I find the Docs confusing especially for my case since I already had a Postgres DB set up and used sequelize-auto to create all the models from the existing DB.

Now I have the following:

- Retailers
- Stores

Stores have a FK in retailer_id since Retailers have several Stores, but a single Store belongs to a single Retailer.

I want to retrieve from my Node API a JSON with the following format:

```
[{
    id:"1",
    name: "RetailerName",
    stores: [{
                  id: "1",
                  name: "StoreName",
                  ...
             }]
}]
```

I was thinking of getting all of the retailers, iterate through them and getting all stores based on the "current" retailer id and adding them to retailers, replying that.

However this is not possible without a promise of some sort and since there are better tools to achieve this with sequelize I would like to know how to do this!

Answer (score 1):

Use [sequelize's associations](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/associations/#one-to-many-associations) (One-To-Many in this particular case)

Comment: Yes, that's what I saw, but I really need help regarding where to put everything because I didn't understand a thing of what's on the Doc. I had this:  var Retailer = models.retailers;
    var Store = models.stores;
    Retailer.hasMany(Store);

Is it right?

Comment: @Forget try exact example from doc replacing user/project with retailer/store, there is no rocket science there

Comment: But do I just put it in my main.js before initializing the server for example? That's what I didn't understand. Where do I put it as there is no context in the docs.

Comment: @Forget you can start with some online tutorials https://egghead.io/lessons/node-js-sequelize-model-definition-basics

Comment: The examples all are creating the database from scratch. And then use Project and User after creation. How do I access the ones I already have? Is it through the models folder?